# how to set permanently fix proxy setting in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, proxy

when i change proxy setting manualy after enter passward chenge proxy but i seclect 'none'or automatic chenge all proxy in pc

i want when select manual put proxy setting is never change by any other selection of 'automatic' and 'none' 
And fix by manualy

Comment: It might help if you specify about where exactly you want to change those proxy settings - system wide, I guess? In commandline shell? One of graphic environments? Which one - KDE, Gnome, Unity, whatever-else? If you give some more details, someone may give you some more detailed answer.

Comment: thnxs for reply i want to manual input proxy setting and this is applying for systum wide and can not be change anyother way but change by me and iwant also password protected  
yes you guess right it is applying for system wide and which one can be easire to fix proxy by terminal or unity but i have hardly knowledge of both

Comment: In bash shell - for commandline operations you can use commands like this (of course with a proper proxy server definded):   "export http_proxy=http://your.proxy.server:port/"      and     "export https_proxy=http://your.proxy.server:port/"

Comment: As for Unity settings - quite honestly I don't remember right now out of my head - but I guess google will help you with that. Most likely somewhere in settings, network section or something like that.